# Updating a cell from another cell in DataGrid GWT without redraw or refresh

Tags: gwt, mvp

I am creating application that contains a `DataGrid` which has 4 columns `(name, hours, rate, total)`.

What I want is to update the *total* cell whenever the *hours* or *rate* values changes.

you may say:

`object.setTotal(object.getHours() * object.getRate());`

...but I want to know how to update the cell value itself without redrawing the row or the DataGrid. Is this possible?

I got the answer:
I used DOM to access the control and update the value. of course I named each control in the DataGrid, for example First row (id=name0, id=hours0, rate0, total0) and so on.

`InputElement ele = DOM.getElementById( "total" + context.getIndex()).cast();`
                                            `ele.setValue(object.getTotal());`

Comment: I guess you were looking an answer like this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401923/gwt-datagrid-inserting-widget-into-the-column

Answer (score 3):

Cells, individually, cannot be refreshed. But row refresh is possible.
So, whenever hours/rate value changes you trigger the row refresh API.

```
dataGrid.redrawRow( rowIndex );
```

Above code refreshes the entire row identified by the index 'rowIndex'

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without redaraw, refresh or setData

Comment: I got the answer: I used DOM to access the control and update the value. of course I named each control in the DataGrid, for example First row (id=name0, id=hours0, rate0, total0) and so on.

InputElement ele = DOM.getElementById( "total" + context.getIndex()).cast(); ele.setValue(object.getTotal());

Comment: @Abhijith and Adarsha. I told you so :). I should have had a bet on this.

Comment: I was about to give the same answer. But there is problem with that approach. I hope you will not face it, if you face it comment back... @SSR Spot on